# Debug navigation in xcode: How do you navigate to the current cursor position?

Tags: xcode, debugging

While debugging in xcode:
How do you navigate to the current cursor position.
This is really easy in Visual Studio, using the debug button in the top menu.
Something similar must be possible in xcode. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also easy in Xcode, extracted from documentation :

"To continue execution to a specific line of code, hold the pointer over the gutter next to the target code line until the continue-to-here icon appears, then click the icon."

[image: xcode-debug]

Edit :

You can simply click on the latest method presented in the debug bar (the screen show the thread, but you can directly click on the stack) :
[image: xcode-debug-bar]

From the Xcode guide : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW27

Comment: Thanks Kenji,
But i want to go the other way around.
Not to move the program cursor to my pointer, but rather move to the file and exact line where the program cursor is waiting. Ex. on a break point.

Comment: Maybe you can use the debug navigator, it shows all threads stacks, on the left of the workspace : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html

Comment: Edited my answer to add navigation from the debug bar (i released that I was using this to go back to my breakpoint :-) )